# Calling the function as a float in C

Tags: c

I'm working with functions in C. How would the code look like if I wanted to return void taxCalculator(); to int main() as float, so it could be printed there.

This is how the code looks like:

The definition on the top

```
void taxCalculator(float income, float tax);
```

The main Function:

```
int main(void){
float income, tax;

printf("Enter the amount of income: ");    
scanf("%f", &income);
taxCalculator(income, tax);
}
```

And the taxCalculator function:

```
void taxCalculator(float income, float tax)
{
if( income < 750.00f){
    tax = income * 0.01f;
}else if (income <= 2250.00f){
    tax = 7.50f + (income - 750) * 0.02f;
}else if (income <= 3750.00f){
    tax = 37.50f + (income - 2250) * 0.03f;
}else if (income <= 5250){
    tax = 82.50f + (income - 3750) * 0.04f;
}else if (income <= 7000){
    tax = 142.50f + (income - 5250) * 0.05f;
}else if(income > 7000.00f){
    tax = 230.00f + (income - 7000) * 0.06f;
}
printf("The amount of tax: %.2f", tax);

}
```

Comment: You are using `float`, so why would it return an `int`? Also, you should generally prefer `double` over `float`.

Comment: you are correct my dear sir.

Comment: And please return a value from `main()` enable compiler warnings, they will save you a lot of time.

Comment: @iharob: As of C99, reaching the closing `}` at the end of `main` does an implicit `return 0;`. Returning a value explicitly still isn't a bad idea (and gcc, for example, doesn't enforce C99 rules by default).

Comment: @KeithThompson good clarification, I always use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` with `gcc` and it makes you learn the best practices in my opinion, besides saves you from many silly mistakes.

Comment: @iharob: You might also use `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` if you want to use features from one of the newer standards. gcc uses `-std=gnu90` by default; that's C90 with GNU extensions. There are also `-std=gnu99` and `-std=gnu11` options. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Standards.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could something like this

```
float taxCalculator(float income) {
  ...
  return tax;
}

...

printf("The amount of tax: %.2f", taxCalculator(income));
```

When the function gets executed, when it terminates it will be replaced with its return value, so `printf()` will use that value for printing.

---

Complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float taxCalculator(float income) {
  float tax;
  if (income < 750.00f) {
    tax = income * 0.01f;
  } else if (income <= 2250.00f) {
    tax = 7.50f + (income - 750) * 0.02f;
  } else if (income <= 3750.00f) {
    tax = 37.50f + (income - 2250) * 0.03f;
  } else if (income <= 5250) {
    tax = 82.50f + (income - 3750) * 0.04f;
  } else if (income <= 7000) {
    tax = 142.50f + (income - 5250) * 0.05f;
  } else if (income > 7000.00f) {
    tax = 230.00f + (income - 7000) * 0.06f;
  }
  return tax;
}

int main(void) {
  float income = 2250;
  printf("The amount of tax: %.2f", taxCalculator(income));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tax` is not used as input, so no need for it as a parameter.

Comment: Still need to remove `tax` from the function call :)

Comment: If I delete the tax from function call, it shows an error

Comment: @TacoCat did you forgot to change the prototype of the function?

Comment: @TacoCat did you declare `float tax;` inside your function?

Comment: *EDIT I see what you did there, that works perfectly, thank you. :)

Comment: You are welcome @TacoCat, I like that you want to learn. +1 from me! (I will give it tomorrow, hope I do not forget, because I have reached the limit in voting!).

Comment: Yeah, I've been having a hard time wrapping my head around functions. But slowly I'm getting there. Thanks.

Comment: If it weren't an utopia I'd upvote your answer just for defining negative taxes ... ;-)

Comment: @alk the magic-logic of the function goes to TacoCat, so does the credit! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could return the tax be wqriting the result to a memory location passed to the function:

```
void taxCalculator(float income, float * ptax)
{
    float tax; 
    ... // init tax here
    printf("The amount of tax: %.2f", tax);

    *ptax = tax;
}
```

call it like so:

```
int main(void)
{
  float income, tax;

  ...

  taxCalculator(income, &tax);

  ...
```

You then are free to use the return value of as error indicator:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include ...

int taxCalculator(float income, float * ptax)
{
    float tax; 

    if ((0. > income) || (NULL == ptax))
    {
      errno = EINVAL;
      return -1;
    }
    ... // init tax here

    *ptax = tax;

    return 0;
}
```

and call it like this

```
   int result = taxCalculator(income, &tax);
   if (-1 == result)
   {
     perror("taxCalculator() failed");
   }
   else
   {
     printf("The amount of tax: %.2f", tax);
   }
```

Comment: I think that the purpose is to put the function inside the `printf()`. If so that approach does not help much IMHO.

Comment: That's the spirit! Agreed! :D

Comment: @alk I like it, I would upvote for you, but I have reached the daily limit for votes, sorry!